# How do you process multiple fields running through a pipe?

Tags: bash, pipe, cut, io-redirection

If I have a tab delimeted data file **input.dat** with a format like:

```
#id  acct    name   city          age
 12  100290  Sally  San Francisco 24
 15  102911  Jerry  Sacramento    40
 99  102134  Amir   Eureka        82
```

Can I use `cut(1)` or something similar to run multiple processing functions ex:( `lookup_id, scrub_acct, scrub_name, lookup_city, scrub_age`) per field as the data runs through a pipe?

It's easy to do this with one field:

`cat input.dat | cut -f1 | lookup_id > output.dat`

but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this per field, and have the results redirected to **output.dat**.

```
#id  acct    name   city          age
 AA  XXXXX0  SXXXX  city-57       20s
 AC  XXXXX1  JXXXX  city-29       40s
 AF  XXXXX4  AXXXX  city-100      80s
```

Maybe a pre-question is can you (do this simply)?

I'm also considering how `paste(1)` might be an alternative to just glue the columns back together, but maybe there's a better way.

Comment: I suggest to take look at `awk`.

Comment: ah good point, I guess you could run a function on each field and kick off a subshell. Is there not a way to do this with cut? Awk is such a beast sometimes. @Cyrus

Comment: So `lookup_id, scrub_acct, scrub_name, lookup_city, scrub_age` are shell functions?

Comment: some of them may be, others might be doing an api call or  a database query. @anubhava

Comment: Your question is very unclear! What are `lookup_id`, `scrub_acct` and so on supposed to do and what parameters are they supposed to take?

Comment: I made the functions up just as an example of the input -> output per field dynamic. @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is easier to process row, column data in `awk` but due to involvement of shell functions it is better to handle this in shell itself.

Assuming `lookup_id, scrub_acct, scrub_name, lookup_city, scrub_age` are shell functions or scripts that are reading input from stdin you can create an array of them and call them while looping through each record from input file:

```
# example shell functions
lookup_id() { read str; printf "lookup_id: %s\n" "$str"; }
scrub_acct() { read str; printf "scrub_acct: %s\n" "$str"; }
scrub_name() { read str; printf "scrub_name: %s\n" "$str"; }
lookup_city() { read str; printf "lookup_city: %s\n" "$str"; }
scrub_age() { read str; printf "scrub_age: %s\n" "$str"; }    

# array of functions or scripts to be invoked
fnarr=(lookup_id scrub_acct scrub_name lookup_city scrub_age)

# main processing
while IFS=$'\t' read -ra ary; do
   for ((i=0; i<${#ary[@]}; i++)); do
      # call function for each field value
      "${fnarr[i]}" <<< "${ary[i]}"
   done
   echo '============================='
done < <(tail -n +2 file)
```

**Output:**

```
lookup_id: 12
scrub_acct: 100290
scrub_name: Sally
lookup_city: San Francisco
scrub_age: 24
=============================
lookup_id: 15
scrub_acct: 102911
scrub_name: Jerry
lookup_city: Sacramento
scrub_age: 40
=============================
lookup_id: 99
scrub_acct: 102134
scrub_name: Amir
lookup_city: Eureka
scrub_age: 82
=============================
```

Comment: variable substitution, very clever. You use that as a sort of dispatcher, thanks for the idea!

Comment: `"${fnarr[i]}" <<< "${ary[i]}"`, to be more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this with awk:

```
awk -F'\t' '{system("lookup_id "  $1); printf("\t"); \
             system("scrub_acct " $2); printf("\t"); \
             ...
            }' input.dat
```